# Determine which middleware answered on ASP.NET Core websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to determine (on way back) which middleware answered the request? 
Is there a stacktrace somewhere or something similar?

What I seek could be a stacktrace up to the last middleware called, accessible in the httpcontext object.

I could add some fake middlewares just setting flags, but I would prefer to have something that does not need adding code.

It would be for example to differenciate requests that have been served by static files and those served by MVC (this is an example, but not exhaustive, I have several middlewares serving response, and I would like to be able to identify which one).

Comment: You could use reflection to determine that and log it.

Comment: Chances are that they are all involved in the response, because that’s how the middleware pipeline works. – Why do you want to know this? If you want to differentiate static files and MVC, you could just add a middleware between them.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I believe reflexion would tell me during the call, but not after

Comment: @poke I have custom logging behaviors, and I would like to log differently static and non-static responses (and I have also other middleware that may give the response before the MVC). I would like an efficient way to find this information.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core Logging API already provide what you need.
You can obtain the following output :

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>     Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/todo/0
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
>         Executing action method TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetById (TodoApi) with arguments (0) - ModelState is Valid
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:44301/css/bootstrap.css
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[2]
>         Sending file. Request path: '/css/bootstrap.css'. Physical path: XXX

The simpliest way of achieving this would be to create an `appsettings.Development.json` file where you can set the following configuration :

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console":
    {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    }
  }
}
```

By default, you will be able to see the logs in the console. You could change where the logs are displayed by using differents `ILoggerProvider`.

I recommend you to read the [Logging chapter on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for a basic log, neither to parse the site logs. 
I am looking for a way to have the information on the middleware that answered to add it as a parameter to a custom logger and avoid additional treatment in case of static files.
Of course one option is to have different middlewares at different stages of the pipe, but I cannot modify all pipes so a single middleware handling all cases would be great :) 

What I seek could be a stacktrace up to the last middleware called, accessible in the httpcontext object or similar.